# BufferedReader gives missing characters

Tags: java, bufferedreader

So I am trying to change the format of a text file that has line numbers every couple of lines just to make it cleaner and easier to read. I made a simple program that goes in and replaces all of the first three characters of a line with spaces, these three character spaces are where the numbers can be. The actual text doesn't start until a few more spaces in. When i do this and have the end result printed out it comes out with a diamond with a question mark in it and I'm assuming that this is the result of missing characters. It seems like most of the missing characters are the apostrophe symbol. If anyone could let me know how to fix it i would really appreciate it :)

```
public class Conversion {
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader scan = null;
    try {
        scan = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("C:\\Users\\Nasir\\Desktop\\Beowulftesting.txt")));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("failed to read file");
    }

    String finalVersion = "";
    String currLine;
    while( (currLine = scan.readLine()) !=null){
        if(currLine.length()>3)
            currLine = "   "+ currLine.substring(3);

        finalVersion+=currLine+"\n";
    }

    scan.close();  
    System.out.println(finalVersion);
}
}
```

Comment: How are you viewing these text files?

Comment: Can you isolate the part of the input file where that happens, and post it together with the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Instead of using `FileReader`, use an `InputStreamReader` with the correct text encoding. I think the strange characters are appearing because you're reading the file with the wrong encoding.
2. By the way, don't use `+=` with strings in a loop, like you have. Instead, use a `StringBuilder`:

   ```
   StringBuilder finalVersion = new StringBuilder();
   String currLine;
   while ((currLine = scan.readLine()) != null) {
       if (currLine.length() > 3) {
           finalVersion.append("   ").append(currLine.substring(3));
       } else {
           finalVersion.append(currLine);
       }
       finalVersion.append('\n');
   }
   ```

Comment: Why can't you use `+=` with strings? `string += .....` compiles to a `StringBuilder` anyway. Although I would agree with you because it looks a lot cleaner.

Comment: @JoshM Running `string += ...` in a loop will result in O(n²) performance, as a new string has to be built for each iteration, copying the (increasingly longer) string each time. `StringBuilder` does not build the new string until you call `toString` on it.

Comment: Oh, I never took that into consideration, thanks for enlightening me about that.